# How to get all objects that have child objects

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

My posts model has nested attributes called feedbacks, crowdfundings, and ideas.

I want to write a method that shows a list of all Posts with feedbacks, all posts with crowdfundings, and all posts with ideas. How do I accomplish this? In my mind it's something like:

```
Post.find(feedbacks.present?)
```

or

```
Post.all where (feedbacks.present)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
Post.includes(:feedbacks).where.not(feedbacks: { id: nil })
```

Or:

```
Post.joins(:feedbacks)
```

Comment: `joins` is truly the correct answer as this will create an `INNER JOIN` and exclude all records that do not have an existing `Feedback` record. `includes` will create a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and then have to use the where clause to filter the unwanted records.(May be some performance implications with this as the application grows).